# Having a shared code in several contexts in EF overriding SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, architecture, dbcontext

I'm working on an application, where there are about 5 contexts, each one corresponds to a database schema(schemas like Accounts, Sales, Purchases.. etc) in the database, all of them connect to the same database.
now I'm building a feature that stores audit in the database, this is a shared feature by all contexts, basically, I override `SaveChanges` method, and there I save the `ChangeTracker.Entries` in the `Audit` table which exists in the `CommonContext`, now I want to apply this same code in all context, I'm thinking in these two options:

-Having a table in every context and copy/paste the auditing code in all of them (terrible option).

-calling and opening the `CommonContext` in all contexts, which seems to me not good practice (opening a context inside another context!, I'll have to reference to the CommonContext Library ).

These are the only options I can think of, so I ask here for help!

I'm using EF 6 database-first.

Comment: I think if you make CommonContext to Base context and inherit it from other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is creating some common cross-cutting concern infrastructure, so duplication and inheritance are not good choices here. You should rather create repositories with common interface accessing entities in your contexts, than create a decorator of repository for auditing purposes holding your CommonContext internally. You must be also sure that CommonContext and the others share the same connection and run under the same TransactionScope.